# Change Username Color in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my laptop, I recently set up Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, and I noticed that the username was green like so.

[image: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows]

Now on my other computer, I installed Bash on Ubuntu on Windows almost immediately when it became available, but the colorization is not there. Instead, everything is all white. How can I reconfigure my old computer to show the colorization in the same way that my laptop does?

Comment: [Change your bash prompt](http://ezprompt.net/)

Comment: Are you wanting to change the color of just the prompt itself or were you wanting all text to be green?

Comment: @n8te I just want to change the color of the "David@David" part as well as the tilde. As for the rest of the text, I want it to remain white.